# What is causing these strange mail logs?

Tags: email, log-files, courier

I was recently going over some old mail logs, and I came across this:

```
Jun 12 14:51:56 hostname imapd: LOGIN FAILED, user=Purple, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1]
Jun 12 14:51:56 hostname postfix/smtpd[21538]: disconnect from 75-145-26-162-Washington.hfc.comcastbusiness.net[75.145.26.162]
Jun 12 14:51:58 hostname postfix/smtpd[21536]: connect from 75-145-26-162-Washington.hfc.comcastbusiness.net[75.145.26.162]
Jun 12 14:52:02 hostname postfix/smtpd[21537]: disconnect from 75-145-26-162-Washington.hfc.comcastbusiness.net[75.145.26.162]
Jun 12 14:52:03 hostname imapd: LOGIN FAILED, user=Sports, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1]
Jun 12 14:52:07 hostname postfix/smtpd[21559]: connect from 75-145-26-162-Washington.hfc.comcastbusiness.net[75.145.26.162]
Jun 12 14:52:09 hostname postfix/smtpd[21536]: disconnect from 75-145-26-162-Washington.hfc.comcastbusiness.net[75.145.26.162]
Jun 12 14:52:11 hostname imapd: LOGIN FAILED, user=dragon, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1]
Jun 12 14:52:14 hostname postfix/smtpd[21562]: connect from 75-145-26-162-Washington.hfc.comcastbusiness.net[75.145.26.162]
Jun 12 14:52:17 hostname postfix/smtpd[21559]: disconnect from 75-145-26-162-Washington.hfc.comcastbusiness.net[75.145.26.162]
Jun 12 14:52:18 hostname imapd: LOGIN FAILED, user=michael, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1]
```

Why would courier-imapd be reporting login failures coming from 127.0.0.1?

**Edit:** While squirrelmail is installed, it's restricted to one IP address, and there are no logs indicating it has been accessed. Further, I'm the sole user of the machine so it's definitely not me. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some digging and it turns out that Postfix is using SASL for authentication, which is authenticating against the local courier-imapd - hence the logs.

Answer (score 1):

squirrel (or any other) webmail comes to my mind...

Comment: While installed, it's IP address restricted, and there are no logs of it being accessed.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a webmail installed in the same server, so authentication are comming from localhost (127.0.0.1 is localhost)

Comment: Squirrelmail is installed, but it's restricted to one IP address, and there are no logs to indicate that it's been accessed.

Comment: You can try to track which from which application the connection is comming with a tool such a lsof

Answer (score 0):

As it has been mentioned, it would have to be something on the local machine connecting to the mail server via the local loopback (or using "localhost" as the server name).

Most commonly, webmail, but could be anything which has the ability to talk across this "interface" .. Eg: if you were running any MUA on the machine it could be causing this behavior.  Or alternatively, if you are running a web server and have code which uses php's imap_open() function and using "localhost" as the mail server name.. or (insert an other  language which runs on the machine which could be doing this)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what it could be. As per my edit, it's not webmail, and being the sole user of the machine, it's not me.

Comment: you could try a command similar to: "netstat -tnp | grep 127.0.0.1" - the output of which should give you some idea which program is creating this connection.   The problem with this is you would need to be running it when the connection is actually established, so it is a bit hit and miss.. 

Alternatively is there a way to increase the verbosity of the logging?! (I am not familiar with courier-imap)

Answer (score 0):

Check the web server logs at the same time of imapd fail login. So you can confirm or not the access is made by Squirrelmail and from where.

Comment: Only appears in the mail log.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read with attention your logs! Now I edited my answer.